# Radiobuttons and viewmodel with variable amount of options in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have been stuck at this all morning. My situation:

I have a list of questions. Every question has a variable amount of answers. These questions and answers get loaded from a datasource and displayed.

This is how I display the questions and answers.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Answer", "Questions", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    foreach (var question in (ICollection<MyNamespace.Models.Question>)ViewData["Questions"])
    {
        <h3>@Html.Encode(question.text)</h3>
        if (question.Answers.Count > 0)
        {
            <ul class="list-inline">
                @foreach (var answer in (ICollection<MyNamespace.Models.Answer>)question.Answers)
                {
                    <li>@Html.Encode(answer.text)</li>
                }
            </ul>
        }
    }
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Complete" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Basically I want to add a radiobutton per answer. I have no idea, however, how to make the ViewModel look like. There is no fixed length on answers or questions.

Perhaps I am going by it all wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you check Html.RadioButtonFor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After like 10 pages of google results I found a post from 2012 explaining the exact thing I need (even in the same context, what are the odds?)

http://techiesweb.net/2012/10/12/radio-button-list-in-asp-net-mvc.html

Hope it helps someone else too!